# How to install Need For Speed Most Wanted in Playonlinux? The game fails to launch on 64 bit systems

Tags: wine, playonlinux

Heres my playonlinux debug logfile:

```
[05/11/16 14:11:31] - Running wine- --version (Working directory : /usr/share/playonlinux/python)
wine-1.6.2

PlayOnLinux logfile
-------------------
Date: 05/11/16 14:11:31

> PlayOnLinux Version
  4.2.10
> uname -a
  Linux Kunji-PC 4.4.0-22-generic #39-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 5 16:53:32 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
> lsb_release -a

> wine --version
  wine-1.6.2
> POL_WINEVERSION

> WINEPREFIX
  /home/shuaib/.PlayOnLinux//wineprefix/NFSMW
> Distribution
  Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
> glxinfo \| grep rendering
  direct rendering: Yes
> glxinfo \| grep renderer
      GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, 
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, 
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile 
> OpenGL libs (Direct rendering testing)
  32bits direct rendering is enabled
  64bits direct rendering is enabled

[05/11/16 14:11:32] - This is a 32bits prefix!
[05/11/16 14:11:35] - Running wine- cmd /c echo %ProgramFiles% (Working directory : /usr/share/playonlinux/python)
C:\Program Files
[05/11/16 14:11:39] - Running wine- winecfg (Working directory : /home/shuaib/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/NFSMW)
[05/11/16 14:12:28] - Running wine- /home/shuaib/Downloads/Win/[R.G. Mechanics] Need for Speed Most Wanted Black Edition/setup.exe (Working directory : /)
fixme:process:SetProcessDEPPolicy (1): stub
fixme:process:SetProcessDEPPolicy (1): stub
fixme:win:DisableProcessWindowsGhosting : stub
fixme:msg:ChangeWindowMessageFilter c03d 00000001
fixme:msg:ChangeWindowMessageFilter c03d 00000001
fixme:msg:ChangeWindowMessageFilter c03d 00000001
fixme:msg:ChangeWindowMessageFilter c03d 00000001
fixme:shell:SHAutoComplete stub
fixme:msg:ChangeWindowMessageFilter c03d 00000001
fixme:wincodecs:PngDecoder_Block_GetCount 0x18fb68,0x33fab8: stub
fixme:wincodecs:PngDecoder_Block_GetCount 0x18fbe8,0x33fab8: stub
fixme:wincodecs:PngDecoder_Block_GetCount 0x18d110,0x33fab8: stub
fixme:wincodecs:PngDecoder_Block_GetCount 0x18d110,0x33fab8: stub
fixme:wincodecs:PngDecoder_Block_GetCount 0x18d2e8,0x33fab8: stub
fixme:wincodecs:PngDecoder_Block_GetCount 0x18d2e8,0x33fab8: stub
fixme:wincodecs:PngDecoder_Block_GetCount 0x18d2e8,0x33fab8: stub
fixme:wincodecs:PngDecoder_Block_GetCount 0x18d2e8,0x33fab8: stub
fixme:wincodecs:PngDecoder_Block_GetCount 0x18d2e8,0x33fab8: stub
fixme:wincodecs:PngDecoder_Block_GetCount 0x18d2e8,0x33fab8: stub
fixme:wincodecs:PngDecoder_Block_GetCount 0x18d2e8,0x33fab8: stub
fixme:wincodecs:PngDecoder_Block_GetCount 0x18d2e8,0x33fab8: stub
fixme:wincodecs:PngDecoder_Block_GetCount 0x18d180,0x33fab8: stub
fixme:wincodecs:PngDecoder_Block_GetCount 0x191478,0x33fab8: stub
fixme:wincodecs:PngDecoder_Block_GetCount 0x18d2e8,0x33fab8: stub
fixme:wincodecs:PngDecoder_Block_GetCount 0x18d180,0x33fab8: stub
fixme:wincodecs:PngDecoder_Block_GetCount 0x18d2e8,0x33fae8: stub
fixme:gdiplus:resample_bitmap_pixel Unimplemented interpolation 7
fixme:wincodecs:PngDecoder_Block_GetCount 0x1904c8,0x33fae8: stub
fixme:wincodecs:PngDecoder_Block_GetCount 0x18d2e8,0x33fae8: stub
fixme:wincodecs:PngDecoder_Block_GetCount 0x10c7e610,0x33fae8: stub
fixme:wincodecs:PngDecoder_Block_GetCount 0x10da3700,0x33fae8: stub
fixme:wincodecs:PngDecoder_Block_GetCount 0x10dd9878,0x33fae8: stub
fixme:wincodecs:PngDecoder_Block_GetCount 0x10c6b740,0x33fae8: stub
fixme:wincodecs:PngDecoder_Block_GetCount 0x10c98490,0x33fae8: stub
fixme:wincodecs:PngDecoder_Block_GetCount 0x10d10f38,0x33f5b8: stub
fixme:wincodecs:PngDecoder_Block_GetCount 0x10d10f38,0x33f5b8: stub
err:setupapi:do_file_copyW Unsupported style(s) 0x144
fixme:sfc:SfcIsFileProtected ((nil), L"C:\\users\\shuaib\\Application Data\\Need for Speed Most Wanted Black Edition\\Uninstall\\unins000.exe") stub
[05/11/16 14:18:27] - Running wine- winepath -u C:\\users\\shuaib\\Desktop (Working directory : /home/shuaib/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/NFSMW/drive_c)
/home/shuaib/.PlayOnLinux//wineprefix/NFSMW/dosdevices/c:/users/shuaib/Desktop
[05/11/16 14:18:42] - Running wine- winepath -u C:\\users\\shuaib\\Desktop (Working directory : /home/shuaib/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/NFSMW/drive_c)
/home/shuaib/.PlayOnLinux//wineprefix/NFSMW/dosdevices/c:/users/shuaib/Desktop
[05/11/16 14:18:54] - Running wine- nfsmwres.exe (Working directory : /home/shuaib/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/NFSMW/drive_c/Program Files/R.G. Mechanics/Need for Speed Most Wanted Black Edition)
[05/11/16 14:18:55] - Running wine- nfsmwres.exe (Working directory : /home/shuaib/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/NFSMW/drive_c/Program Files/R.G. Mechanics/Need for Speed Most Wanted Black Edition)
[05/11/16 14:19:02] - Running wine- nfsmwres.exe (Working directory : /home/shuaib/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/NFSMW/drive_c/Program Files/R.G. Mechanics/Need for Speed Most Wanted Black Edition)
[05/11/16 14:19:08] - Running wine- speed.exe (Working directory : /home/shuaib/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/NFSMW/drive_c/Program Files/R.G. Mechanics/Need for Speed Most Wanted Black Edition)
wine: Unhandled exception 0xc0000090 in thread 9 at address 0x7ed26975 (thread 0009), starting debugger...
fixme:ole:RemUnknown_QueryInterface No interface for iid {00000019-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
[05/11/16 14:19:38] - Running wine- speed.exe (Working directory : /home/shuaib/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/NFSMW/drive_c/Program Files/R.G. Mechanics/Need for Speed Most Wanted Black Edition)
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x32f894,0x00000000), stub!
wine: Unhandled exception 0xc0000090 in thread 9 at address 0x7ed30975 (thread 0009), starting debugger...
Unhandled exception: invalid float operation in 32-bit code (0x7ea1be07).
Register dump:
 CS:0023 SS:002b DS:002b ES:002b FS:0063 GS:006b
 EIP:7ea1be07 ESP:0032f580 EBP:0032f6d8 EFLAGS:00210297(  R- --  I S -A-P-C)
 EAX:00000003 EBX:7ea66000 ECX:0015a6f0 EDX:0032f660
 ESI:00000000 EDI:0015a6f0
Stack dump:
0x0032f580:  0032f5b8 00000000 0015a548 00000060
0x0032f590:  00000000 00000000 00000000 00400000
0x0032f5a0:  00110000 00000000 001558e8 0032f77c
0x0032f5b0:  7bc8df80 0032f660 7bcbe000 00000002
0x0032f5c0:  0032f85c 00002000 83a9ffa0 6f9cc557
0x0032f5d0:  00000002 00220000 0015a6f0 0001001e
Backtrace:
=>0 0x7ea1be07 in gdi32 (+0x5be07) (0x0032f6d8)
  1 0x7df5be61 in winex11 (+0x1be60) (0x0032f6f8)
  2 0x7df87ac2 in winex11 (+0x47ac1) (0x0032f7e8)
  3 0x7e9dd93e in gdi32 (+0x1d93d) (0x0032f828)
  4 0x7ea10c42 in gdi32 (+0x50c41) (0x0032f8c8)
  5 0x7ea261cd SelectObject+0xec() in gdi32 (0x0032f908)
  6 0x7e9cf480 in gdi32 (+0xf47f) (0x0032f938)
  7 0x7e9cfb59 CreateCompatibleDC+0x178() in gdi32 (0x0032f978)
  8 0x7e81eab8 in user32 (+0x1eab7) (0x0032f9e8)
  9 0x7e81fdd2 in user32 (+0x1fdd1) (0x0032fa58)
  10 0x7e8222a0 LoadImageW+0x27f() in user32 (0x0032fb48)
  11 0x7e822b40 LoadImageA+0x12f() in user32 (0x0032fc78)
  12 0x7e822d30 LoadIconA+0x6f() in user32 (0x0032fcc8)
0x7ea1be07: fldz
Modules:
Module  Address         Debug info  Name (104 modules)
PE    400000-  a78e4e   Export          speed
PE    a80000-  cca000   Deferred        d3dx9_26
ELF 7b800000-7ba54000   Deferred        kernel32<elf>
  \-PE  7b810000-7ba54000   \               kernel32
ELF 7bc00000-7bcda000   Deferred        ntdll<elf>
  \-PE  7bc10000-7bcda000   \               ntdll
ELF 7bf00000-7bf04000   Deferred        <wine-loader>
ELF 7d133000-7d16a000   Deferred        libtxc_dxtn.so
ELF 7d18c000-7d198000   Deferred        libpciaccess.so.0
ELF 7d30f000-7d31d000   Deferred        libdrm_radeon.so.1
ELF 7d31d000-7d327000   Deferred        libdrm_nouveau.so.2
ELF 7d327000-7d34c000   Deferred        libdrm_intel.so.1
ELF 7d34c000-7da06000   Deferred        i965_dri.so
ELF 7da06000-7da23000   Deferred        libgcc_s.so.1
ELF 7da23000-7da2c000   Deferred        librt.so.1
ELF 7da2c000-7da4d000   Deferred        libudev.so.1
ELF 7da4d000-7da5f000   Deferred        libdrm.so.2
ELF 7da5f000-7da7a000   Deferred        libxcb-glx.so.0
ELF 7da7a000-7da96000   Deferred        libglapi.so.0
ELF 7da96000-7db05000   Deferred        libgl.so.1
ELF 7db27000-7db5b000   Deferred        ws2_32<elf>
  \-PE  7db30000-7db5b000   \               ws2_32
ELF 7db5b000-7db80000   Deferred        iphlpapi<elf>
  \-PE  7db60000-7db80000   \               iphlpapi
ELF 7db80000-7dbac000   Deferred        netapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7db90000-7dbac000   \               netapi32
ELF 7dbac000-7dbcf000   Deferred        tapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7dbb0000-7dbcf000   \               tapi32
ELF 7dbcf000-7dbf9000   Deferred        msacm32<elf>
  \-PE  7dbd0000-7dbf9000   \               msacm32
ELF 7dbf9000-7dcb1000   Deferred        winmm<elf>
  \-PE  7dc00000-7dcb1000   \               winmm
ELF 7dcb1000-7dcf8000   Deferred        dsound<elf>
  \-PE  7dcc0000-7dcf8000   \               dsound
ELF 7dcf8000-7dd2d000   Deferred        uxtheme<elf>
  \-PE  7dd00000-7dd2d000   \               uxtheme
ELF 7dd2d000-7dd34000   Deferred        libxfixes.so.3
ELF 7dd34000-7dd3f000   Deferred        libxcursor.so.1
ELF 7dd3f000-7dd52000   Deferred        libxi.so.6
ELF 7dd52000-7dd56000   Deferred        libxcomposite.so.1
ELF 7dd56000-7dd63000   Deferred        libxrandr.so.2
ELF 7dd63000-7dd6f000   Deferred        libxrender.so.1
ELF 7dd6f000-7dd76000   Deferred        libxxf86vm.so.1
ELF 7dd76000-7dd7a000   Deferred        libxinerama.so.1
ELF 7dd7a000-7dd81000   Deferred        libxdmcp.so.6
ELF 7dd81000-7dd85000   Deferred        libxau.so.6
ELF 7dd85000-7ddab000   Deferred        libxcb.so.1
ELF 7ddab000-7def6000   Deferred        libx11.so.6
ELF 7def6000-7df0b000   Deferred        libxext.so.6
ELF 7df0b000-7df11000   Deferred        libxcb-dri2.so.0
ELF 7df11000-7df14000   Deferred        libx11-xcb.so.1
ELF 7df14000-7df18000   Deferred        libxdamage.so.1
ELF 7df18000-7df1b000   Deferred        libxshmfence.so.1
ELF 7df1b000-7df23000   Deferred        libxcb-sync.so.1
ELF 7df23000-7df27000   Deferred        libxcb-present.so.0
ELF 7df27000-7df2b000   Deferred        libxcb-dri3.so.0
ELF 7df2d000-7dfba000   Dwarf           winex11<elf>
  \-PE  7df40000-7dfba000   \               winex11
ELF 7e048000-7e071000   Deferred        libexpat.so.1
ELF 7e071000-7e0ba000   Deferred        libfontconfig.so.1
ELF 7e0ba000-7e0e5000   Deferred        libpng12.so.0
ELF 7e0e5000-7e100000   Deferred        libz.so.1
ELF 7e100000-7e1b0000   Deferred        libfreetype.so.6
ELF 7e1d2000-7e2c7000   Deferred        comctl32<elf>
  \-PE  7e1e0000-7e2c7000   \               comctl32
ELF 7e2c7000-7e33d000   Deferred        shlwapi<elf>
  \-PE  7e2d0000-7e33d000   \               shlwapi
ELF 7e33d000-7e566000   Deferred        shell32<elf>
  \-PE  7e350000-7e566000   \               shell32
ELF 7e566000-7e57a000   Deferred        shfolder<elf>
  \-PE  7e570000-7e57a000   \               shfolder
ELF 7e57a000-7e5f6000   Deferred        rpcrt4<elf>
  \-PE  7e590000-7e5f6000   \               rpcrt4
ELF 7e5f6000-7e725000   Deferred        ole32<elf>
  \-PE  7e610000-7e725000   \               ole32
ELF 7e725000-7e741000   Deferred        dinput8<elf>
  \-PE  7e730000-7e741000   \               dinput8
ELF 7e741000-7e7f0000   Deferred        msvcrt<elf>
  \-PE  7e750000-7e7f0000   \               msvcrt
ELF 7e7f0000-7e93e000   Dwarf           user32<elf>
  \-PE  7e800000-7e93e000   \               user32
ELF 7e93e000-7e9aa000   Deferred        advapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7e950000-7e9aa000   \               advapi32
ELF 7e9aa000-7eac1000   Dwarf           gdi32<elf>
  \-PE  7e9c0000-7eac1000   \               gdi32
ELF 7eac1000-7ebdf000   Deferred        opengl32<elf>
  \-PE  7eae0000-7ebdf000   \               opengl32
ELF 7ebdf000-7ed11000   Deferred        wined3d<elf>
  \-PE  7ebf0000-7ed11000   \               wined3d
ELF 7ed11000-7ed4e000   Deferred        d3d9<elf>
  \-PE  7ed20000-7ed4e000   \               d3d9
ELF 7ef4e000-7ef61000   Deferred        libnss_files.so.2
ELF 7ef61000-7ef6e000   Deferred        libnss_nis.so.2
ELF 7ef6e000-7ef89000   Deferred        libnsl.so.1
ELF 7ef89000-7efde000   Deferred        libm.so.6
ELF 7efe7000-7f000000   Deferred        version<elf>
  \-PE  7eff0000-7f000000   \               version
ELF f741b000-f7420000   Deferred        libdl.so.2
ELF f7420000-f75d6000   Deferred        libc.so.6
ELF f75d7000-f75f4000   Deferred        libpthread.so.0
ELF f75f6000-f7600000   Deferred        libnss_compat.so.2
ELF f7616000-f77cb000   Dwarf           libwine.so.1
ELF f77cd000-f77f2000   Deferred        ld-linux.so.2
ELF f77f4000-f77f5000   Deferred        [vdso].so
Threads:
process  tid      prio (all id:s are in hex)
00000008 (D) C:\Program Files\R.G. Mechanics\Need for Speed Most Wanted Black Edition\speed.exe
    00000023    1
    00000022    2
    00000009    0 <==
0000000e services.exe
    0000001f    0
    0000001e    0
    00000019    0
    00000018    0
    00000016    0
    00000014    0
    00000010    0
    0000000f    0
00000012 winedevice.exe
    0000001d    0
    0000001a    0
    00000017    0
    00000013    0
0000001b plugplay.exe
    00000021    0
    00000020    0
    0000001c    0
00000024 explorer.exe
    00000026    0
    00000025    0
```

And heres the crash report:

```
Unhandled exception: invalid float operation in 32-bit code (0x7eb22f57).
Register dump:
 CS:0023 SS:002b DS:002b ES:002b FS:0063 GS:006b
 EIP:7eb22f57 ESP:0033f510 EBP:0033f688 EFLAGS:00210297(  R- --  I S -A-P-C)
 EAX:00000000 EBX:7eb6f000 ECX:0014bd60 EDX:0033f610
 ESI:00000000 EDI:0014bd60
Stack dump:
0x0033f510:  00000000 00000000 00000000 a450bf00
0x0033f520:  7d02d014 7bc3df36 0033f550 7bc3e066
0x0033f530:  0033f550 7bcd5000 0033f5b8 7bc5162f
0x0033f540:  0033f610 0033f598 7bc5028d 0033f800
0x0033f550:  00002000 00000002 0033f5b8 7bc51520
0x0033f560:  001456c8 0014bd60 0001001e 00110000
Backtrace:
=>0 0x7eb22f57 in gdi32 (+0x62f57) (0x0033f688)
  1 0x7de8bb31 in winex11 (+0x1bb30) (0x0033f6a8)
  2 0x7deb7c82 in winex11 (+0x47c81) (0x0033f798)
  3 0x7eae42de in gdi32 (+0x242dd) (0x0033f7d8)
  4 0x7eb176fd in gdi32 (+0x576fc) (0x0033f8c8)
  5 0x7eb2de6d SelectObject+0xec() in gdi32 (0x0033f908)
  6 0x7ead5720 in gdi32 (+0x1571f) (0x0033f938)
  7 0x7ead5de9 CreateCompatibleDC+0x178() in gdi32 (0x0033f978)
  8 0x7e91a138 in user32 (+0x1a137) (0x0033f9e8)
  9 0x7e91b452 in user32 (+0x1b451) (0x0033fa58)
  10 0x7e91d890 LoadImageW+0x27f() in user32 (0x0033fb48)
  11 0x7e91e130 LoadImageA+0x12f() in user32 (0x0033fc78)
  12 0x7e91e320 LoadIconA+0x6f() in user32 (0x0033fcc8)
0x7eb22f57: fldz
Modules:
Module  Address         Debug info  Name (107 modules)
PE    400000-  a78e4e   Export          speed
ELF 7a800000-7a930000   Deferred        opengl32<elf>
  \-PE  7a820000-7a930000   \               opengl32
ELF 7b800000-7ba63000   Deferred        kernel32<elf>
  \-PE  7b810000-7ba63000   \               kernel32
ELF 7bc00000-7bcf2000   Deferred        ntdll<elf>
  \-PE  7bc10000-7bcf2000   \               ntdll
ELF 7bf00000-7bf04000   Deferred        <wine-loader>
ELF 7cff6000-7d02d000   Deferred        libtxc_dxtn.so
ELF 7d3a4000-7da5e000   Deferred        i965_dri.so
ELF 7daee000-7dafa000   Deferred        libpciaccess.so.0
ELF 7dafa000-7db08000   Deferred        libdrm_radeon.so.1
ELF 7db08000-7db12000   Deferred        libdrm_nouveau.so.2
ELF 7db12000-7db37000   Deferred        libdrm_intel.so.1
ELF 7db37000-7db54000   Deferred        libgcc_s.so.1
ELF 7db54000-7db5d000   Deferred        librt.so.1
ELF 7db5d000-7db7e000   Deferred        libudev.so.1
ELF 7db7e000-7db90000   Deferred        libdrm.so.2
ELF 7db90000-7db96000   Deferred        libxcb-dri2.so.0
ELF 7db96000-7dbb1000   Deferred        libxcb-glx.so.0
ELF 7dbb1000-7dbcd000   Deferred        libglapi.so.0
ELF 7dbcd000-7dc3c000   Deferred        libgl.so.1
ELF 7dc5d000-7dc64000   Deferred        libxfixes.so.3
ELF 7dc64000-7dc6f000   Deferred        libxcursor.so.1
ELF 7dc6f000-7dc82000   Deferred        libxi.so.6
ELF 7dc82000-7dc86000   Deferred        libxcomposite.so.1
ELF 7dc86000-7dc93000   Deferred        libxrandr.so.2
ELF 7dc93000-7dc9f000   Deferred        libxrender.so.1
ELF 7dc9f000-7dca6000   Deferred        libxxf86vm.so.1
ELF 7dca6000-7dcaa000   Deferred        libxinerama.so.1
ELF 7dcaa000-7dcb1000   Deferred        libxdmcp.so.6
ELF 7dcb1000-7dcb5000   Deferred        libxau.so.6
ELF 7dcb5000-7dcdb000   Deferred        libxcb.so.1
ELF 7dcdb000-7de26000   Deferred        libx11.so.6
ELF 7de26000-7de3b000   Deferred        libxext.so.6
ELF 7de40000-7de43000   Deferred        libx11-xcb.so.1
ELF 7de43000-7de47000   Deferred        libxdamage.so.1
ELF 7de47000-7de4a000   Deferred        libxshmfence.so.1
ELF 7de4a000-7de52000   Deferred        libxcb-sync.so.1
ELF 7de52000-7de56000   Deferred        libxcb-present.so.0
ELF 7de56000-7de5a000   Deferred        libxcb-dri3.so.0
ELF 7de5c000-7deeb000   Dwarf           winex11<elf>
  \-PE  7de70000-7deeb000   \               winex11
ELF 7deeb000-7df23000   Deferred        ws2_32<elf>
  \-PE  7def0000-7df23000   \               ws2_32
ELF 7df23000-7df4c000   Deferred        iphlpapi<elf>
  \-PE  7df30000-7df4c000   \               iphlpapi
ELF 7df4c000-7df7b000   Deferred        netapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7df50000-7df7b000   \               netapi32
ELF 7df7b000-7df9e000   Deferred        tapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7df80000-7df9e000   \               tapi32
ELF 7df9e000-7dfc8000   Deferred        msacm32<elf>
  \-PE  7dfa0000-7dfc8000   \               msacm32
ELF 7dfc8000-7e080000   Deferred        winmm<elf>
  \-PE  7dfd0000-7e080000   \               winmm
ELF 7e080000-7e0ca000   Deferred        dsound<elf>
  \-PE  7e090000-7e0ca000   \               dsound
ELF 7e0ca000-7e141000   Deferred        shlwapi<elf>
  \-PE  7e0e0000-7e141000   \               shlwapi
ELF 7e141000-7e37d000   Deferred        shell32<elf>
  \-PE  7e150000-7e37d000   \               shell32
ELF 7e37d000-7e391000   Deferred        shfolder<elf>
  \-PE  7e380000-7e391000   \               shfolder
ELF 7e391000-7e3ad000   Deferred        dinput8<elf>
  \-PE  7e3a0000-7e3ad000   \               dinput8
ELF 7e3ad000-7e3d1000   Deferred        imm32<elf>
  \-PE  7e3b0000-7e3d1000   \               imm32
ELF 7e467000-7e490000   Deferred        libexpat.so.1
ELF 7e490000-7e4d9000   Deferred        libfontconfig.so.1
ELF 7e4d9000-7e504000   Deferred        libpng12.so.0
ELF 7e504000-7e51f000   Deferred        libz.so.1
ELF 7e51f000-7e5cf000   Deferred        libfreetype.so.6
ELF 7e5f0000-7e66f000   Deferred        rpcrt4<elf>
  \-PE  7e600000-7e66f000   \               rpcrt4
ELF 7e66f000-7e7a6000   Deferred        ole32<elf>
  \-PE  7e690000-7e7a6000   \               ole32
ELF 7e7a6000-7e7cd000   Deferred        d3dxof<elf>
  \-PE  7e7b0000-7e7cd000   \               d3dxof
ELF 7e7cd000-7e843000   Deferred        d3dcompiler_43<elf>
  \-PE  7e7e0000-7e843000   \               d3dcompiler_43
ELF 7e843000-7e8d0000   Deferred        d3dx9_36<elf>
  \-PE  7e850000-7e8d0000   \               d3dx9_36
ELF 7e8d0000-7e8eb000   Deferred        d3dx9_26<elf>
  \-PE  7e8e0000-7e8eb000   \               d3dx9_26
ELF 7e8eb000-7ea3b000   Dwarf           user32<elf>
  \-PE  7e900000-7ea3b000   \               user32
ELF 7ea3b000-7eab0000   Deferred        advapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7ea50000-7eab0000   \               advapi32
ELF 7eab0000-7ebcb000   Dwarf           gdi32<elf>
  \-PE  7eac0000-7ebcb000   \               gdi32
ELF 7ebcb000-7ed11000   Deferred        wined3d<elf>
  \-PE  7ebe0000-7ed11000   \               wined3d
ELF 7ed11000-7ed4f000   Deferred        d3d9<elf>
  \-PE  7ed20000-7ed4f000   \               d3d9
ELF 7ef4f000-7ef62000   Deferred        libnss_files.so.2
ELF 7ef62000-7ef6f000   Deferred        libnss_nis.so.2
ELF 7ef6f000-7ef8a000   Deferred        libnsl.so.1
ELF 7ef8a000-7efdf000   Deferred        libm.so.6
ELF 7efe6000-7f000000   Deferred        version<elf>
  \-PE  7eff0000-7f000000   \               version
ELF f738a000-f7540000   Deferred        libc.so.6
ELF f7540000-f7545000   Deferred        libdl.so.2
ELF f7546000-f7563000   Deferred        libpthread.so.0
ELF f7566000-f7570000   Deferred        libnss_compat.so.2
ELF f7584000-f773b000   Dwarf           libwine.so.1
ELF f773d000-f7762000   Deferred        ld-linux.so.2
ELF f7764000-f7765000   Deferred        [vdso].so
Threads:
process  tid      prio (all id:s are in hex)
00000008 (D) C:\Program Files (x86)\NFS Most Wanted\speed.exe
    00000028    1
    00000027    2
    00000009    0 <==
0000000e services.exe
    0000001e    0
    0000001d    0
    00000014    0
    00000010    0
    0000000f    0
00000012 winedevice.exe
    0000001c    0
    00000019    0
    00000018    0
    00000013    0
0000001a plugplay.exe
    00000020    0
    0000001f    0
    0000001b    0
00000021 explorer.exe
    00000026    0
    00000025    0
    00000024    0
    00000023    0
    00000022    0
System information:
    Wine build: wine-1.8
    Platform: i386 (WOW64)
    Version: Windows 7
    Host system: Linux
    Host version: 4.4.0-21-generic
```

Comment: I'd recommend first to try later wine version, e.g. 1.8, or better 1.9. Wine is a permanently evolving soft, and 1.6 is really old.

Comment: In this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9HZRkvw_-fM he used 1.5.30 so I don't think it's th version that's the problem. One thing I've noticed though, is that people running wine amd64 always have more problems. In playonlinux installed versions of wine amd64 don't even show in the list. Only i386 versions are listed.

Comment: Actually no, [I see in appdb most worked Wine versions are x86-64](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=8714). I see there was 1.6.1, then 1.7.0, perhaps there was some kind of regression? Try a later version.

Comment: Also, try to install it without playonlinux, perhaps it would change anything. But upgrade wine anyway.

Comment: On Ubuntu 22.04, PlayOnLinux does not work, so I found the alternative to solve the problem: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1437380/ubuntu-22-04-how-to-run-an-exe-file-by-the-desktop-shortcut